# Subscript Out of Range Error - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I know this issue has been frequently discussed but I still can't find a fix 
for it. I am getting the `Subscript out of range error` and this occurs
on and off.

Sometimes the program runs but sometimes it gets stucked.

- The program gets stuck on the following line.
- The same declarations with other worksheets did not have this problem.
- I only have one workbook open and I prefer
  to use `Activeworkbook` rather than specifying the Excel file.

  Set shAuditTrail = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("AuditTrail")

[image]
I have tried the following

1. Switching the code to name `Sheet5` instead of the worksheet name.
2. Making sure name is correct by printing out all worksheet names in
   Immediate Window.

---

Okay, after I opened and repaired the file, it seems to work. For those who
don't know how to do open and repair a corrupt workbook, here are the steps
(from MS support).

And [this](http://www.contextures.com/excelvbatips.html) blog offers some tips on troubleshooting the same issue. (Although it didn't offer the solution of repairing the workbook.)

I appreciate all those who responded and tried to help.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell what is happening here. Is the variable empty/nothing before you look to set it? The code runs okay at times? You are completey sure you are referring to the right workbook?

Comment: I only have one workbook open. And this error does not occur to other sheets. Yes, variable is empty before setting it. What else can I try?

Comment: Guessing now. Suggest you select all sheets, right click, select "move or copy", tick `create a copy` and move them to a new workbook. Move your code as well. This should rebirth your worksheet and take out corruption of your workbook as a possibility.

Comment: What changes between runs? Do you import new data? Edit cells? what is occurring that is different? Is the AuditTrail sheet updated in the script or created during the script? When the error occurs, does it keep occurring if you rerun the script without closing it or is it intermittent even if nothing changes in the data and you don't close/reopen excel? Is there anything that you can do to ensure that it will happen when you run it?

Comment: @dombey sounds like it may have been corruption if the open and repair fixed it. Suggest you post this as a self-solution. Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: I can't post a solution if this questions is on-hold.

Answer (score 3):

> I only have one workbook open and I prefer to use Activeworkbook rather than specifying the Excel file.

If your macro is only ever intended to run against the AuditTrail `Worksheet` *in the same* `Workbook` then you should use `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Set shAuditTrail = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AuditTrail")
```

Comment: Agree with Robin...best to use ThisWorkbook.  It's possible that another workbook could be open and active when the code runs if that workbook doesn't have a sheet called "AuditTrail" then you would get the error.

Comment: From the OP post this isn;t going to address the issue.